# AMP: add <table> to a <div>

Tags: javascript, wordpress, amp-html

I use a jQuery script to append all the `<table>`s of a WordPress post to a `<div>` with the class `.table_container`.

This way, I can make every table scrollable on mobile devices on already posted articles.

jQuery:

```
for (var r = document.querySelectorAll("#post table"), m = 0; m < r.length; m++) {
    var i = r[m],
        d = document.createElement("div");
    i.parentElement.insertBefore(d, i), d.className = "table_container", d.appendChild(i)
}
e(".table_container").before("<small>Scroll to see more</small>");
```

CSS:

```
.post .table_container {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

How can I do the same on **AMP**, since it's not possible to use Javascript?

I am currently using [AMP for WP](https://ampforwp.com/)

Comment: AMP now supports [javascript](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/custom-javascript/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since AMP does not allow arbitrary JS, one of the [applied design principles](https://www.ampproject.org/about/amp-design-principles/) is to solve issues like this at the right layer (e.g. server side, CSS). In your particular case, you can make the tables scrollable using only CSS as described [here](https://codepen.io/cssgrid/pen/pRXQzW):

```
table {
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

or you can generate the markup in PHP as suggested in a prior answer. These approaches remove the need of JS code, making them suitable to AMP.

Comment: That's a really good approach that I didn't know. Thank you, Alberto.

Answer (score 0):

The not-so-pretty answer is... use PHP.

```
<?php
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
$content = str_replace('<table', '<div class="table_container"><table', $content);
$content = str_replace('</table>', '</table></div>', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: If you're doing this to cover off on older posts to make them fit your new layout, you could run a SQL replace (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp) on the older posts through the database and fix them for good. Or perhaps I have misunderstood and you're only doing this on mobile?

Comment: This is only for mobile and I for sure don't want to add <div>s to post's content, since they can be easily removed on visual editing. 
But thank you for your help!